# Select Top n Values Across Columns and Average

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table that has `13 columns`, one with type `varchar(25)` and the rest with type `int (holding values for each month of the year).

For each row, I would like to pick the `top 6 int` values from the `12 columns` and calculate the average of those values.

I know how to select the top n from a given column, but how do you do it across multiple columns?

Answer (score 4):

```
select ID,
       (
       select avg(C)
       from (
            select top(6) C
            from (values(C1),(C2),(C3),(C4),(C5),(C6),(C7),
                        (C8),(C9),(C10),(C11),(C12)) as T(C)
            order by C desc
            ) as T
       ) as C
from YourTable
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53591/1)

For SQL Server 2005 it would look like this since you can't use the [Table Value Constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)

```
select ID,
       (
       select avg(C)
       from (
            select top(6) C
            from (select C1 union all
                  select C2 union all
                  select C3 union all
                  select C4 union all
                  select C5 union all
                  select C6 union all
                  select C7 union all
                  select C8 union all
                  select C9 union all
                  select C10 union all
                  select C11 union all
                  select C12) as T(C)
            order by C desc
            ) as T
       ) as C
from YourTable
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53591/2)

And for SQL Server 2000 this could work for you.

```
select T1.ID,
       avg(C) as C
from (
     select ID, C1 as C from YourTable union all
     select ID, C2  from YourTable union all
     select ID, C3  from YourTable union all
     select ID, C4  from YourTable union all
     select ID, C5  from YourTable union all
     select ID, C6  from YourTable union all
     select ID, C7  from YourTable union all
     select ID, C8  from YourTable union all
     select ID, C9  from YourTable union all
     select ID, C10 from YourTable union all
     select ID, C11 from YourTable union all
     select ID, C12 from YourTable
     ) as T1
where (
      select count(*)
      from (
           select ID, C1 as C from YourTable union all
           select ID, C2  from YourTable union all
           select ID, C3  from YourTable union all
           select ID, C4  from YourTable union all
           select ID, C5  from YourTable union all
           select ID, C6  from YourTable union all
           select ID, C7  from YourTable union all
           select ID, C8  from YourTable union all
           select ID, C9  from YourTable union all
           select ID, C10 from YourTable union all
           select ID, C11 from YourTable union all
           select ID, C12 from YourTable
           ) as T2
      where T1.ID = T2.ID and
            T1.C <= T2.C
      ) <= 6
group by T1.ID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53591/5)

I would not expect this to be particularly fast. Perhaps a better option is to store an intermediate result in a temp table.

```
create table #T
(
  ID varchar(25),
  C int
)

insert into #T
select ID, C1 as C from YourTable union all
select ID, C2  from YourTable union all
select ID, C3  from YourTable union all
select ID, C4  from YourTable union all
select ID, C5  from YourTable union all
select ID, C6  from YourTable union all
select ID, C7  from YourTable union all
select ID, C8  from YourTable union all
select ID, C9  from YourTable union all
select ID, C10 from YourTable union all
select ID, C11 from YourTable union all
select ID, C12 from YourTable

select T1.ID,
       avg(C) as C
from #T as T1
where (
      select count(*)
      from #T as T2
      where T1.ID = T2.ID and
            T1.C <= T2.C
      ) <=  6 
group by T1.ID  

drop table #T
```

Comment: @GaryGerson You should be able to alter this query slightly to work in sql server 2000 -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53591/4

Comment: @GaryGerson please always tag your questions with the right SQL Server version, *especially* if you're using a version that is (a) nearly 14 years old (b) 4+ major versions obsolete and (c) completely out of any type of Microsoft support.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is important to understand that using TOP in conjunction with aggregates will not limit the aggregation but rather the result set.  Look at this example:

```
SELECT TOP 2 SUM(col) FROM
(SELECT 1 AS col
 UNION
 SELECT 2
 UNION
 SELECT 3)sq
```

The result is still "6".

Secondly, aggregation does NOT work across columns, only rows.  You would need to evaluate them manually.  Probably the most efficient way would be to create a table from the row like this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT MAX(myval) FROM (values (col1), (col2), (col3), (col4)) as all_values(myval))
FROM (SELECT 1 as col1, 2 as col2, 3 as col3, 4 as col4)sq
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later you can `unpivot` the `table`, then `rank` the values,  and last calculate the `averages` the for the `top 6 values` per `identifier`.

something like this:

```
;WITH UnPivoted AS (
    SELECT pk, MonthID, MonthNumber, MonthValue
    FROM 
       (SELECT pk, Month1, Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5, Month6, Month7, Month8, Month9, Month10, Month11, Month12
       FROM pvt) p
    UNPIVOT
       (pk FOR MonthNumber IN 
          (Month1, Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5, Month6, Month7, Month8, Month9, Month10, Month11, Month12)
    )AS unpvt
),
UnPivotedRanked AS (
    SELECT pk, MonthValue, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY pk ORDER BY MonthValue DESC) AS pkRanked
    FROM UnPivoted
    GROUP BY pk
)
SELECT pk, AVG(MonthValue) AS Top6Average
FROM UnPivotedRanked
WHERE pkRanked < 6
GROUP BY pk
```

Comment: RANK doesn't break ties, you probably want ROW_NUMBER

Comment: Using SQL 2000, unfortunately.